# Download images and save locally on iPhone Phonegap app

Tags: javascript, iphone, download, offline, cordova

I've already managed to save a web page (x/html) successfully, but I'd also like to save the images and mp4 videos that are contained in it, for further visualization in offline mode.

I've got access to the iOS filesystem, so I save the html by obtaining the code through an AJAX request, and later saving it to a file.

I don't really know how to do the same with **video** and **images**. I have a server to which I can send queries from my app, so it shows exclusively the content I need to download, with the optimal headers in case its necessary. I just don't know how to "download" it from the client side (**Javascript**).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Any update on this? What did you decide ultimately?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`FileTransfer`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) object to download a remote image to a local file.

This is the latest official sample snippet:

```
    // !! Assumes filePath is a valid path on the device

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/download.php");

    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        filePath,
        function(entry) {
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        },
        false,
        {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: can you please tell me what will be the `filepath` if I want to save the image inside the app? like www/something/file.jpg.

Comment: What do you mean inside the app? You'll need to save it in the SDCard or in an internal memory directory. The web page is compiled in the app resources and you can't write there.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it natively I'm afraid.
I'm doing it through a FileDownload PhoneGap Plugin that I wrote, using NSURLConnection. I pass in the url to download to the plugin through Javascript, and a target location (and it even gives me download progress).

Comment: Hi, would it be possible for you to share your code? I'd be willing to donate if I can achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested it yet, but the documentation at PhoneGap looks quite promising http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used this snippet on my ios app project:

```
 window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, fail);

 var target_directory="";

 function fail() {
   //alert("failed to get filesystem");
 }

 function downloadImage(url, filename){
   alert("download just started.");
    try{
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.download(
           url,
           target_directory + filename, 
           function(entry) {
              //alert("download complete!:" + entry.nativeURL ); //path of the downloaded file 
           },
           function(error) {
              //alert("download error" + error.code);
              //alert("download error" + JSON.stringify(error));
           }
       );
   }
   catch (e){
       //alert(JSON.stringify(e));
   }

}

function success(fileSystem) {
   target_directory = fileSystem.root.nativeURL; //root path 
    downloadImage(encodeURI("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg"), "cat.jpg"); // I just used a sample url and filename
}
```